# Show DIV after button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have checked other answers, but none of them seemed to work for me. I have a form that has a hidden DIV with a drop down list. I want it to be visible only when the button is clicked. I created following code with a button. So when button is clicked, it would show the the hidden div but every time I clicked on the button, nothing happened.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="_form.php" method="POST">
    <div class="row">
    <input type=button value="Already a Supplier" name="supplier">      
    </div>
 </form>

 <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['supplier']))
    {
??php

<div class="row" style="visibility: hidden" name="suppliers">
<?php $supplier = SupplierHead::model()->findAll();
      $list = CHtml::listData($supplier ,'head_id','head_name'); 
      echo $form->DropDownList($model,'party_id', 
      $list, array('prompt'=>'Select Supplier')); 
?>
</div>

<?php

  }
?>
```

Comment: have to tried it with `jquery`?

Comment: "??php" is that a typo? Also, you have "visibility: hidden", so it won't show up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery's [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) method.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q2Ru5/

HTML:

```
<select class="hideDefault">
   <option>Option 1</option>
   <option>Option 2</option>
   <option>Option 3</option>
</select>

<button class="unHide">Unhide the dropdown</button>
```

CSS:

```
 .hideDefault { display: none; }
```

jQuery:

```
$(".unHide").click(function() {
    $(".hideDefault").show();
});
```

What you're essentially doing is loading the dropdown, hiding it, and waiting for the click() event on the button with .unHide class, and it shows the dropdown by targeting (or selecting) the class.

Probably worth noting that if you haven't used jQuery before, you'll have to reference a copy of jQuery library to use this.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery like below. Use `display` instead of `visibility`

```
<div class="row" id="toshow" style="display:none" name="suppliers"> <?php $supplier = SupplierHead::model()->findAll();
       $list = CHtml::listData($supplier ,'head_id','head_name'); 
       echo $form->DropDownList($model,'party_id', 
       $list, array('prompt'=>'Select Supplier'));  ?> </div>

    <button id="abutton">Click</button>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#abutton").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#toshow").css('display', 'block');
       });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<script>
    function show() 
            {
                document.getElementById("suppliers").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
</script>

<div class="row" id="suppliers" style="visibility:hidden" name="suppliers">Content of div</div>
<input type="button" value="show" onClick="show()"/>
```